# How do you get past Nocturnal's statue on the Pilgrim's Path?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

This is the 3rd "test" of 5 on the infamous Pilgrim's Path, and in order to pass, I must open the rock-door. Unlike other gates of its kind, there is seemingly no lever or pull-chain that raises it. So, I must believe that the statue of Nocturnal is in some way important. Also, it would seam that the journal of a failed explorer holds a riddle relating to this very test.

> "Offer what she desires most, but reject the material. For her
>   greatest want is that which cannot be seen, felt, or carried"

Help a poor Nightingale out?

Answer (score 9):

I have figured it out! You need to douse the torches in the room, as Nocturnal is the lady of shadows.

Comment: Hey! Click the "right" button on the left of this answer, near the up and down arrows to set this as your selected answer if you aren't wait for any better answers. The button is on gray.

Comment: I think the problem for most people is not seeing the chains in the first place rather  than not realizing both fires should be out

Answer (score 3):

According to my gameplay and [this](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Darkness_Returns) wiki:

There is two sconces near the statue in the third trial of this quest, on the right side of the right sonce you can see a chain, pull it. And to the sonce, in the left side of it, another chain, pull it too. This way the room will get dark and the path will open.

Comment: Just noticed you figured it out, sorry, I'll keep the answer if anyone seeks more details.

Answer (score 0):

Next to nocturnal are two lights. Next to those are chains hanging down below them. Pull the chain and the light will go out. Do the same with the other one. When both lights are off, the door will open. Nocturnal is a lady of Night! And it's in the name "Nocturnal" and "Night"engales. XD have fun playing!

Comment: This question was answered 5 years ago, you haven't added anything new

Answer (score -5):

I used a wooden plate and just sprinted threw the door like it wasent even there  o bring 2 wooden plates  you will need to get back lol